# MySQL CREATE command denied to user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a script system that refuse to be installed because of error that breaks installation.

I tryied to import the data by import the data via .sql file at phpmyadmin and it still cant import.

When i try to menully import the file jcqm.sql its fail and i get this message:

> SQL query: - --—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—- —Table `jqcm_import`.`users` -
>   --—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jqcm_import`.`users` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `uuid` CHAR
>   NOT NULL, `username` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL, `email` VARCHAR NULL
>   DEFAULT NULL, `password` VARCHAR NOT NULL, `role` ENUM NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT ‘USER’, `status` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, `date_created`
>   TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL, `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT
>   NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username`
>   ASC), UNIQUE INDEX `uuid_UNIQUE` (`uuid` ASC)) ENGINE = InnoDB
>   AUTO_INCREMENT = 0 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8; MySQL said:
>   Documentation #1142 – CREATE command denied to user ‘xxx’@’localhost’
>   for table ‘users’

I try to grant some privilegies by do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `costo_jmat`.* TO 'costo_matis'@'localhost'
```

By using this method:

> GRANT ALL on dbname.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by
>   'password'

But still, no sucsess!

Here is the installation path: [Installation path](http://cor.co.il/api/install/index.php)

Can you please solve this so i can use the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GRANT you specified a database name of `costo_jmat`. But your import has a database name of `jqcm_import`. Fix that.

Comment: Also, does the `jqcm_import` database actually exist?

Comment: I change the correct DB name, but i cant create users or tests!